# Modeling advice: scheduling problem with judged events and "blocks" of judging assignments

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint-programming

I am considering a scheduling problem in which the events are officiated, likely as a MILP problem. I'm getting hung up on how best to model a particular requirement of how the judged events are scheduled. Any advice would be most welcome.

Here is a small description with the salient details:

$E = \{1, 2, ..., n_e\}$ : set of events to be judged

$D_e$ : anticipated duration of event $e$ in minutes, $\forall e \in E$

$J = \{1, 2, ..., n_j\}$ : set of judges

A judge from $J$ is pre-assigned to officiate one or more events from $E$.

$V = \{1, 2, ..., n_v\}$ : set of venues for the events

The day's activity in each venue commences at the same start time.

A judge's assignments are to be partitioned into "blocks" of events of no more than 60 minutes. If an event $e$'s duration $D_e >= 60$ minutes, then it is to be in a block on its own.

Then, these blocks are to be scheduled in venues from $V$, to start on a 5-minute marker (e.g. 8:00, 8:05, 8:10, ...). For example, suppose from the table below that we choose a block [1, 2, 3] for a judge, and choose to schedule it at 8:00 a.m. in venue 6. Then event 1 will begin at 8:00 a.m., event 2 at roughly 8:20 a.m., and event 3 at 8:34 a.m.; and the next block of events at venue 6 could begin no sooner than 8:45 a.m. (the nearest 5-minute marker past 8:42 a.m., the putative end time of the [1, 2, 3] block).

There are constraints and penalties for certain characteristics of these block schedulings:

- use all venues
- prevent overlap of blocks in same venue
- prevent overlap of a judge's blocks scheduled in different venues
- afford some time gap between blocks in same venue
- afford some time for each judge to have lunch
- encourage finishing all events as soon as possible
- encourage solutions that minimize:

  - the number of times a judge must switch venues
  - the number of equipment changes needed between events
  - overlaps between multiple events in which a participant is entered

For a given judge, there are potentially lots of possibilities for blocks of their judging assignments. I'm getting hung up on how best to represent these possibilities and the choices thereof.

Suppose a judge is pre-assigned to officiate these events:

| event number (e) | D_e |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 30 |
| 5 | 36 |
| 6 | 18 |

Then $\{[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]\}$ is a legitimate judging assignment (I'm using square brackets here to represent sequences: event 1 is followed immediately by event 2). So is $\{[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]\}$...or any other set of permutations of $\{1, 2\}$, $\{3, 4\}$, and $\{5, 6\}$. It's as though we can find any partition of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ in which each of the subsets obeys the 60-minute duration limit ... and then any of those subsets can be permuted to give a different sequencing for the block it represents.

One possibility might be to pre-enumerate such block partitions/permutations for each judge, then have decision variables $PP_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$ where 1 = that partition/permutation possibility is used, so that $\sum_{i \in B} PP_{ij} = 1, \forall j \in J$. Then choose start times for each block in the partition/permutation possibilities chosen. This yields possibly way too many variables.

Another possibility I've considered: Suppose a judge $j$'s assignment is $\{e_1, e_2, ..., e_{m_j}\}$. Then let each judge $j$ have a maximum of $m_j$ blocks
available. Then let $b_{ijk} = 1$ if event $i$ occupies position $j$ in block $k$, else 0. Constrain $b_{ijk}$ appropriately so that every event occupies exactly one
position in exactly one block; and for every block $b$, if it's unused, then so is block $b + 1$; and that the sum of the durations of the events in each block is acceptable.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Would you please, give more details about the problem description? What does set $J$ mean? what you mean by `these blocks are to be scheduled in a venue, to start on a 5-minute marker (e.g. 8:00, 8:05, 8:10, ...).` If the duration is pre-determined, what is $D_e \leq 60$?

Comment: @A.Omidi Thanks for responding. I'll make edits to clarify.

Comment: In the industry hundreds of thousands of variables/constraints exist but mostly will be within a limited number of possibilities. In your case something needs to be parameterized like schedule of blocks; block 1 begin at 8 at venues in V, block 2 at 8:20 and so on. Also it may be simpler to schedule events or assign to blocks as a new model. Then add assignment of judges as an update or new model.

Comment: It's like in ML, any variable with high cardinality or high variance is too random to be a good predictor and so is often factored out.

Comment: @Sutanu thanks for your feedback. I should clarify that the decisions here are: when to schedule each event, and in what venue. Every event's judge is considered fixed. The extra wrinkle is to schedule the events in "blocks" as described above.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies it a bit, judge-event assignment is fixed. I will try to put something in the answer today/tomorrow/Thanksgiving holidays but no promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-define nB number of blocks where $n \le \lvert E \rvert$ where E is set of events, e. Blocks could be set as time slots alternatively.
$B =\{b_1,b_2,..b_n \}$
Combinations already available: judge pre-assigned to events.
$JE =\{je_{1,1},je_{2,1},..je_{j,e} \}$
Venue, $V = \{v_1,v_2,..v_n \}$
Define more combinations of events, E with Venue, V. Instead of adding constraints latter better to define combinations of possible events with venues along with blocks.
$EBV =\{ebv_{1,1,1},ebv_{2,1,1},..ebv_{e,b,v} \}$
Also assuming every venue will have total time, $T_v$ available
Define DVs:
$x_{e,b,v}, \ y_{j,v} \ and \ z_{j,b} $ as binary.
$bigM = \lvert E \rvert*\lvert V \rvert*\lvert B \rvert$

Constraints:
$\sum_{b}\sum_{v} x_{e,b,v} = 1\quad \forall\ e \in E$: $\quad$Event can be assigned to one block in one venue.

$\sum_{e} x_{e,b,v}*D_e \le 60\quad  \forall\ b  \in B \quad \forall\ v \in V$: $\quad$ Total duration of blocks.

$\sum_{b}(\sum_{e} x_{e,b,v}*D_e + \sum_{e} x_{e,b,v}*D_e\pmod 5) = T_v \quad \forall\ v  \in V$:  This ensures blocks are sequenced in a way that takes care of 5 minute marker.

$bigM*y_{j,v} \ge \sum_{e \in\ JE}\sum_{b \in B} X_{e,b,v} \quad \forall\ v \in V \quad\ \forall\ j \in J$: Counts number of venues a judge is assigned

$bigM*z_{j,b} \ge \sum_{e \in\ EJ}\sum_{v \in JV} X_{e,b,v} \quad \forall b \in B \quad \forall J \in J$: Counts number of blocks a judge is assigned

$\sum_e x_{e,b+1,v} \le bigM*\sum_{e} x_{e,b,v} \ \forall b \in B \quad \forall v \in V$: Condition for b+1 to be empty if b is empty at a venue, v

totalDuration = $\sum_{e,b,v \in EBV} x_{e,b,v}$
venueChange = $\sum_{j}\sum_{v} y_{j,v}$
NblockJudge = $\sum_{j}\sum_{b} z_{j,b}$
$Minimize \ \{venueChange+ NblockJudge + totalDuration\}$

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It lends some legitimacy to my thoughts about modeling blocks of events. I appreciate you taking the time to post a possible solution.